# Unable to load Material-UI icons

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, icons

I have an issue with my icons displaying:

Here is my code:

```
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';

<Button variant='contained' className={classes.sendButton}>
    Search
    <img src={SearchIcon} alt='search'/>
</Button>
```

However, in the UI it gets rendered with the default 'broken-page' symbol. There is no error in console.
I have npm installed the latest @material-ui/icons=^4.9.1

I am unable to ascertain what is causing this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ciao, to show Material UI icon is not necessary to use `img` tag. Just write:

```
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';

<Button variant='contained' className={classes.sendButton}>
    Search
    <SearchIcon />
</Button>
```

And you should see your icon in button.

Anyway, I suggest you to use `startIcon` Button prop like:

```
<Button
   variant='contained' 
   className={classes.sendButton}
   startIcon={<SearchIcon />}
>
   Search
</Button>
```